# How to achieve NSUserDefaults concept in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, nsuserdefaults

In iPhone we are using NSUserDefaults to temporarily store the data (around 30 images and texts) for a custom list view. How can we achieve this in Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using sharedpreferences concept u can achieve this.

see this link:[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

and refer this example:[example for shared preferences](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html)

Comment: But if I am storing those images in sdcard, in this project I am using at least 10 activities.From web services using SOAP I am consuming those image urls and downloading using lazy loading.Thus populating text and image in list view. But now in my app, every time when I am opening each activity it is downloading. I just want to customize it,i.e., it will only download for the first time

Answer (score 4):

SharedPreferences for the texts but for 30 images i would recommend using a folder in sdcard

```
SharedPreferences userPreference = getSharedPreferences("preference name", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: But if I am storing those images in sdcard, in this project I am using atleast 10 activities.From web services using SOAP I am consuming those image urls and downloading using lazy loading.Thus populating text and image in list view. But now in my app, every time when I am opening each activity it is downloading. I just want to customize it,i.e., it will only download for the first time

Comment: yea download once and store in folder, check if not present in folder download but if present in sdcard use it....

Answer (score 1):

Use the concept of SharedPreferences. This will contain the prefs. of the user similar to that of NSUserDefaults. Something like this :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("Sample Preference", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: But if I am storing those images in sdcard, in this project I am using atleast 10 activities.From web services using SOAP I am consuming those image urls and downloading using lazy loading.Thus populating text and image in list view. But now in my app, every time when I am opening each activity it is downloading. I just want to customize it,i.e., it will only download for the first time

Comment: Could you try doing an async download of the images so that the view loads even though the image is not completely loaded ?